# eq and nth-child DOM search

Tags: jquery, css

Through testing in my browser tt appears that eq searches the DOM tree from the top down and stops after it finds the first element.

whereas nth-child searches the entire DOM tree from the top down and along the way targets all relevant elements.

Example:

```
$('div').children('p:nth-child(2)').css('color', 'red')

$('div').children('p').eq(3).text('text edited with (eq)');
```

Does eq actually stop the DOM search once it finds the element?

Comment: Yep, `.eq` and `:nth-child` are different. See http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/. *"The `:nth-child(n)` pseudo-class is easily confused with `:eq(n)`, even though the two can result in dramatically different matched elements."*

Comment: lol thanks, but doesn't answer my question exactly

Comment: Well, the link contains more information. Also have a look at http://api.jquery.com/eq/. `.eq` only returns **one** element (*"Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index."*) whereas `:nth-child` selects all elements that are the n-th child of their parent.

Comment: OK but does it PHYSICALLY stop the DOM search?

Comment: @Aaron, no, it doesn't.

Comment: In case of `$('div').children('p').eq(3)`? No, because at `$('div').children('p')` it does not know about `.eq` yet. You are calling `.eq` *after* you selected all `p` children. The elements are already selected at this point. You just say *"give me the fourth of the selected elements"*. Imagine you do it in two steps: `var $p = $('div').children('p'); var $e = $p.eq(3);`. Of course `$p` contains all `p` elements that are children of `div` elements.

Comment: Derek, please make that an answer so I can see votes.

Comment: Thanks Felix, I appreciate your time :)

Comment: Note that `.eq()` doesn't do a DOM search at all. It selects a specific element _from a jQuery object_ without regard for how that jQuery object was created. It is quite possible to have a jQuery object that has elements in it that or not in the same order as they appear in the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, the entire DOM will be searched first for DIVs.

In the first case, the third child of those DIVs will be checked to see if it is a P.  This is a really short search because it's not looking for the 3rd paragraph but the 3rd child.  So, yes, it stops after the specified nth child, regardless of element type, because it doesn't need to search further.

In the second case, the query searches for all Ps (that are children of those DIVs) and then searches that subset to see if any is the third paragraph. So, in this case it does not stop at the 3rd P because it first finds all the Ps and then whittles down.

Comment: OK makes sense thanks. Still new to SO, I'd give you a +1 but it seems I need 10 points until I can do that :D